# Ordering results from RavenDB

Tags: linq, ravendb

I am using RavenDB and running into problems when trying to order my results.

Here's a sample of the classes.

```
public class Post {
    public int Id {get;get;}
    public DateTimeOffset Posted {get;set;}
    public List<SectionAssignment> Sections{get;set;}
    public string Headline {get;set;}
}
public class SectionAssignment {
    public int SectionId {get;set;}
    public int Priority {get;set;}
}
```

In my controller I am trying to return a set of Posts which is assigned to a specific Section, then order by (desc) the date portion of the Posted property. Then I want to to sort by the SectionAssignment Priority. Here's what I've got:

```
var posts= RavenSession.Query<Post>()
    .Where(s => s.Sections.Any(sec=>sec.SectionId==5))
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Posted.Date)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Section.Where(sec => sec.Id == 5).Select(sc => sc.Priority).Single())
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

I am the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.

I can see why this is happening, but I can't figure out how to make this work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

An educated guess is that it's your ThenBy clause that's causing it to fail.

If I remember correctly, Ordering and Querying *predicates* can't refer to other fields - it's a limitation of Lucene.

A work-around is to instead set up a manual index which pulls out the sorting priority as a field, which you can then order by.